# generate unique 5 digit number

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

i was told to write program which generate  unique 5 digit   number ( for example  12345  is unique  and 11234  not)
 i have write following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
using std::rand;
const int k=99999-10234;
bool  unique(int t){

    map<int,int>my;
    map<int,int>::iterator it;
    while (t!=0){
        ++my[t%10];
    t/=10;
}
    for (it=my.begin();it!=my.end();it++){

        if ( it->second>0) {
             return false;
        }
    }

       return true;
}
int main(){
    int m=0;
     m= 10234+ rand()%k;
    if (unique(m)){
         cout<<" unique number was generated =:"<<m<<" ";
    }
    else{

        do{


             m=10234+rand()%k;
               if (unique(m)){
                   cout<<"unique  number was generated"<<m<<" ";
                break;
               }

    }   while(!unique(m));


    }


     return 0;
}
```

but it does not show me  any output  please help me what is bad in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the line:

```
if ( it->second>0) {
```

Should be:

```
if ( it->second>1) {
```

Since when you find the first instance of a digit and put it in the map it'll have the value 1 for that digit in the map, not 0.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there're easier ways to generate number you need, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> digs;
for (int i = 0; i < 10;++i)
    digs.push_back(i); // Init digits

std::random_shuffle(digs.begin(), digs.end()); // Get random 10-digits number
int result = 0;
int i = 0;
while (result < 10000) { // Get 5-digit number from it
    result*=10;
    result += digs[i];             
    ++i;
}

cout << result << endl;
```

Comment: This is the smarter algorithm. I'd just call `std::copy(digs.begin(), digs.begin() + 5, std::ostream_iterator(std::cout));` directly after the shuffle, though. Why spend 7 lines to get all the decimal digits in an int, when operator<<(ostream&, int) is going to do the reverse work to get them out again?

Comment: Those redundant(?) lines are just to handle the case when 1st digit is '0' - so technically first 5 digits won't produce 5-digit number.